# pass 2 dimensional array as a parameter in a web-service in java

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to make a web-service in java where you pass in a 2 dimensional array as a parameter. When I test it with the web-service explore I keep getting this error:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
  <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing</faultstring> 
- <detail>
  <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Name</ns1:hostname> 
  </detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Any idea as to why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are best off wrappering your two-dimensional array inside of an object, and even then use something like ArrayList instead of an actual Array. It works better with web services with Java and your JAXB bindings.

```
public class MyTwoDimensionalArrayWrapper {
  private Collection dimensionOne = new ArrayList();
  private Collection dimensionTwo = new ArrayList();

  ...
  //getters and setters, etc.
  //note I did not put any annotations on this..just a skeleton to give you an idea to help.
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be a two-dimensional array?

Comment: It is a wrapper around two "arrays", ie, Collections. Those will have to be kept in sync with each other, but the wrapper object can help handle that. If you wanted, you could add other Collections to make it n-dimensional. From my experience with web services any form of array is best done through a wrapper object (especially if you are using the older JAX-RPC API's). Might be extra work. But it eliminates a LOT of headache IMHO.

Comment: Im sorry but what would be a good way to sync this. I mean you cant add an element at [1][2] and [2][2] if you do it this way right?

Comment: Whatever position you add an object to in the first Collection, you add it to in the second Collection. So the first Collection [1] and first location [1] means [1][1]. Second Collection [2] and first location is [1] so that means [2][1]. So if you want the same object or similar objects added at the same time you could do the following: public add(Object obj1, Object obj2) and then add Object one to whichever spot you want (default is next available) and then add second object to second Collection (ie, the next dimension). Make sense?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. What's your algorithm for representing a n^2 sized table with two n sized lists?

Comment: @KublaiKhan I don't have an algorithm per se. I just know that Java does not do conversion of an array very well to web services. It likes "multi-parm" and "array" style things wrappered with another object (especially as Java only allows one return type and technically web services allow more than one). So I've found that wrappering two ArrayLists would be the best way to represent a two-dimensional array. If you needed more dimentions, you can add them. It does force the programmer to have to synchronize the "slots" in the lists, but it works.